# How to match mime-types similar to how the Apache 2 <Files> directive works?

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there a way to match mime-types similar to how the Apache 2 [`Files`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files) directive works?

For example, I might want to apply several customizations to all text/plain mime-types; intentionally not using the file extension or other criteria to match (which could easily be done with `Files`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, it's not possible. Best alternative is to use a `FilesMatch` directive, e.g.:

`<FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|etc)$">`